# Installing PostgreSQL with ArcGIS Desktop without breaking Python?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, postgresql, installation, arcgis-10.5

I am looking to learn PostgreSQL.

I have a current working version of ArcGIS 10.5 with Python version 2.7. I have heard of people having installed another version of Python and having trouble with ESRI Python working after that.

I want to install PostgreSQL (BigSQL installer). This installer includes a version of Python.

**Will installing PostgreSQL cause Python in ArcGIS to stop working?**

I am trying to understand what Postgresql installer BigSQl does with my current installed ArcGIS python version. I am hoping that PostgreSQL and ArcGIS python programs run independent of each other--then there is no issue. If there are issues, I'd like to know BEFORE I install PostgreSQL. There is documentation that ArcGIS program not "playing nice" with other Python versions
[Installing ArcGIS 10 with Python(x,y)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8324/installing-arcgis-10-with-pythonx-y?rq=1)

In Researching, I have discovered that Postgresql Bigsql installer in windows version does change the Python executable in the Pythonpath environment. The source of my info can be found [Here](https://www.bigsql.org/docs/proclang/proclang#plpython). **Does the installer “overwrite” ArcGIS 10.5 Pythonpath OR does the Bigsql installer “add” to the Pythonpath and thus both co-exist without issues?**

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: There are a handful of similar Q&As here regarding issues occurring when installing python on a system that already has ArcGIS's python install already.  Sometimes a repair install of ArcGIS will work (as it resets the links pointing to the ArcGIS python install, however this may in turn break something in your PostgreSQL python install (I don't know if it will, just it might).  You may need to manage your python paths, or you may be able to get PostgreSQL to look at the ArcGIS python

Comment: That is trouble with using repair: it may fix ArcGIS but "Break" Postgresql python. I am hoping someone has done this before and knows the best course to take.

Comment: And Thanks for the Welcome, Midavalo! How do manage python paths?

Comment: Well that depends on what happens. It may not be necessary as it might just work (perhaps after an ArcGIS repair).  You might need to test it and see what happens (do you have a spare/test PC to try it on?)  At the moment you're talking about a "what if?" scenario where there may not even be any issues occurring

Comment: True--I am playing the what if scenario. At the moment I don't have a spare computer--thus why I am asking BEFORE I do it.

Comment: There is no such thing as an Esri Python or a PostgreSQL Python, only multiple Python interpreters installed by different packages.  It's foolish to screw around with the Python releases installed by other applications, but baring that, each package should continue to work correctly.  You'll probably need to name the source of what you heard for it to be taken seriously.

Comment: Vince this is example of ArcGIS not "playing nice" with other Python versions https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8324/installing-arcgis-10-with-pythonx-y?rq=1

Comment: @ShadowLearn Please **[edit]** your question to include additional information

Comment: Middavalo, I am uncertain what additional information your are requesting. Details please.

Comment: @ShadowLearn Your response to comments should be as edits to the question.  Comments are for potential answerers to request clarification and/or more information, your response should be added to  your question.

Comment: @Midavalo So most of my typing should be in the question and others should do most of the comments, correct? (I am replying in comments because this off-topic from the question--just trying to understand how the Q&A site works).

Comment: @ShadowLearn Correct.  Your question should be self-contained - if someone asks for more info or clarification, by updating your question a potential answerer can read your question and get all the info you've provided without having to read through all comments to get a full picture.  Many users don't read through all the comments, particularly if there are many of them.  Having everything in the question means they don't need to.

Comment: @Midavalo Thanks for the info--I will comment less and update the question more. Thanks for helping an newbie! I am learning that asking question is a process.

Comment: @ShadowLearn Happy to help.  The more you use the site, the easier it becomes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed PostgreSQL and have tested out my python scripts that run through python version associated with ArcGIS.  Good news, no issues so far. The difference python versions within PostrgreSql BigSQL and ArcGIS work independent of each other. Sometimes you can't just tip toe around the issue, you have to dive in--thus why I installed PostgreSQL. I took the chance off of researching the info—I didn’t want to risk work critical workflows. Today it worked out.